# new dateobject in EST timezone

Tags: c#

I have a date string in specific format and I am parsing it to my localtime in EST. the data coming in the string is valid in EST. However the datetime object created is in UTC time. how do I fix it?

```
string ibdatetimestring = "20170712  15:26:49";
int year = int.Parse(ibdatetimestring.Substring(0, 4));
int month = int.Parse(ibdatetimestring.Substring(4, 2));
int day = int.Parse(ibdatetimestring.Substring(6, 2));
int h = int.Parse(ibdatetimestring.Substring(10, 2));
int m = int.Parse(ibdatetimestring.Substring(13, 2));
int s = int.Parse(ibdatetimestring.Substring(16, 2));
DateTime bartime = new DateTime(year, month, day, h, m, s, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx) method for this purpose passing the source and destination timezone